# Golang io.Pipe vs node.js Pipe

Tags: go, pipe

I'm new to golang and I'm having problem understanding go's `io.Pipe`. Is this similar to node.js' `.pipe`? And how should I use it? Is it possible to use it with 1 read file and a write file?

Thank in advance guys.

Answer (score 5):

No, they are not precisely similar. `io.Copy(dat io.Writer, src io.Reader)` is quite enough to read and write files, like this:

```
input := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
output := bufio.NewWriter(os.Stdout) // buffer output like C stdlib
io.Copy(output, input)               // copy entire file
output.Flush()
```

`io.Pipe() (*PipeReader, *PipeWriter)` will produce piped `Reader` and `Writer` for you when you have **not them** but code **expect them**, like this:

```
type id struct{
  name string
  age int
}

payload := id{"John", 25}     
requestBody, jsonPayload := io.Pipe()
request := http.NewRequest("POST". "http://www.example.com", requestBody) // NewRequest expect io.Reader
encoder := json.NewEncoder(jsonPayload) // NewEncoder expect io.Writer
err := encoder.Encode(payload)
response, err := client.Do(request)
```